# How do I remove orders from order history under My Account?

Tags: magento

Is there a way to delete/hide (cancelled) orders one by one on My Account page that shows order history?

Comment: you are talking about my account page or my orders page?

Answer (score 0):

Run below SQL for disabling **visible_on_front** parameter for **canceled** order status, which will hide canceled orders from showing on frontend.

> UPDATE sales_order_status_state SET visible_on_front = '0' WHERE
>   sales_order_status_state.status = 'canceled' AND
>   sales_order_status_state.state = 'canceled';